# No alert when input is entered

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am trying to get it so that when I press enter while focused on an input, it alerts something.
I have an input tag,

```
<input></input>
```

Then I have javascript,

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input").keyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("1111");
  }
};
```

Why is this not working? Here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/darkfyi/pen/meBdzZ.

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].keyup`, Note the **[0]**

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` returns a html collection... you need to register the handler to each element in that collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- The `document.getElementsByTagName` method returns a `HTMLCollection`, so you must iterate through this collection, or use the first item by using `[0]`.
- If you want to delegate the event `keyup` by its property, you should use `.onkeyup = function() {`, as there is no `HTMLInputElement.keyup` method. You would use `keyup` in `addEventListener` method, for example.

So, your code should be something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("1111");
  }
};
```

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaGbRM).